# Subsonic 3 - No Fetch, FetchAll, or Scaffolding Control?

Tags: subsonic, fetch, scaffold

I'm fairly new to SubSonic, and downloaded the latest version which only contained a zip file with the folders Binaries, Examples and T4 Templates.  Upon further reading I was looking forward to trying the Scaffolding control, however the DLL contains no tools to add to the VS2008 toolbox.

I'm also unable to use .Fetch, .FetchByID, etc.

I'm using the ActiveRecord pattern, and all table entities are created in ActiveRecord.cs.

I can grab data using the following:

---

```
        var qry = from s in tbl_Geo_State.All()
                  select new
                  {
                      s.State
                  };

        GridView1.DataSource = qry;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

---

Is there a different installation file for 3.0.x.x or should I use an older install version (if so, which), and simply add the new directories to the installation to get the tools and missing methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't need to update the Scaffold - it works great the way it is :). I will be splitting out the "web stuff" into separate DLLs when I have a chance - but for now you can use both 3 and 2 in the same project if you want that control.

RE Fetch and FetchByID - these are static factory methods on the class:

```
Product.SingleOrDefault(...)
Product.Find(...)
Product.All().Where()...
```

etc.